# Sencha touch 2: Set button handler parameter to lunch javascript function

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using the sencha touch o'really example. Is a conference that have sessions and speakers associated. Imagine that I have a session list that when is tapped the view change to the session details.

I have a view like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.session.Detail', {

extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'session',

config: {

    layout: 'vbox',
    title: '',

    items: [
        {
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'fit',
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            xtype: 'sessionInfo'
        },
        {
            flex: 2,
            xtype: 'speakers',
            store: 'SessionSpeakers',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'listitemheader',
                    cls: 'dark',
                    html: 'Speakers'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'button',
            text: "Decline  Button" ,
            handler: function () {
            /*HERE I WANT TO PUT SOME DATA FROM THE SESSION OBJECT. FOR EXAMPLE */ 
                alert({title});
                alert({start_date});
                alert({location});                
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

});
So, I want to replace the {title} {start_date} {location} for the corresponding values of the current session.

By the way in the controller I have this:

```
onSessionTap: function(list, idx, el, record) {

    var speakerStore = Ext.getStore('SessionSpeakers'),
        speakerIds = record.get('speakerIds');

    speakerStore.clearFilter();
    speakerStore.filterBy(function(speaker) {
        return Ext.Array.contains(speakerIds, speaker.get('id'));
    });

    if (!this.session) {
        this.session = Ext.widget('session');
    }

    this.session.setTitle(record.get('title'));
    this.getSessionContainer().push(this.session);
    this.getSessionInfo().setRecord(record);
},
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve it.
I had to create the button on runtime.
:

In Session view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.session.Detail', {

extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'session',

config: {

    layout: 'vbox',
    title: '',

    items: [
        {
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'fit',
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            xtype: 'sessionInfo'
        },
        {
            flex: 2,
            xtype: 'speakers',
            store: 'SessionSpeakers',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'listitemheader',
                    cls: 'dark',
                    html: 'Speakers'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

});

In Session controller:

```
onSessionTap: function(list, idx, el, record) {

    var speakerStore = Ext.getStore('SessionSpeakers'),
        speakerIds = record.get('speakerIds');

    speakerStore.clearFilter();
    speakerStore.filterBy(function(speaker) {
        return Ext.Array.contains(speakerIds, speaker.get('id'));
    });

    if (!this.session) {
        this.session = Ext.widget('session');       
    }
    else{
                  //To avoid multiple buttons
        this.session.removeAt(2);
    }

    this.session.setTitle(record.get('title'));

   this.session.add(
        Ext.Button.create({
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'button',
            text:'My button' ,          
            handler: function () {                  
                alert(record.get('title'));
                                alert(record.get('start_date'));
              } })
    );
    this.getSessionContainer().push(this.session);
    this.getSessionInfo().setRecord(record);
},
```